# how to end an outgoing call after activity result?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have a `outGoingCall` broadcast receiver.

basically I want it to intercept any outgoing call and show a dialog for certain pre-defined numbers.

so I made this `broadcast` init an `activity` which inits an `FragmentDialog` which init a `AlertDialog`.

When the user click `"no"`

I want to stop the call from happening.

I know `setResultData(null);` in the broadcast should do it.

But how can I pass the dialog result to the broadcast ?

there is no `onActivityResult()` in a broadcast.

I know how to pass it till the activity only.

fragmentDialog code:

```
public class YesNoDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private YesNoDialogFragmentListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the
            // host
            mListener = (YesNoDialogFragmentListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
        }
    }
```

here is my activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        YesNoDialogFragmentListener {

    public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        showYesNoDialog();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick() {
// how to send result to receiver ??
        finish();
    }
```

here is my receiver code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    Log.v(Constants.LOGTAG, "OutgoingCallReceiver onReceive");
    if (intent.getAction()
            .equals(OutgoingCallReceiver.OUTGOING_CALL_ACTION)) {
        Log.v(Constants.LOGTAG,
                "OutgoingCallReceiver NEW_OUTGOING_CALL received");

        // get phone number from bundle
        String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(
                OutgoingCallReceiver.INTENT_PHONE_NUMBER);
        if ((phoneNumber != null)
                && phoneNumber
                        .equals(OutgoingCallReceiver.ABORT_PHONE_NUMBER)) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "NEW_OUTGOING_CALL intercepted to number 123-123-1234 - aborting call",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context
                    .getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF_NAME,
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            boolean isBloacked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(
                    Constants.IS_NUMBER_BLOCKED, true);

            if (isBloacked) {
                // dialog and then:
                setResultData(null);
            }
        }
```

as you can see i tried to share the activity result via shared preferences, how come the code is async and the `setResultData(null);` is called before the dialog is shown?

from what I know there is no way to end the call besides `setResultData(null);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through an activity (or a fragment) and then pass it to the receiver. Whenever you start a dialog, it has a parent activity, and that is where the result is sent. Just add something to your activity that passes the result on to your receiver.

You might actually consider altering your design to put more of your logic into the activity. Receivers are generally intended to be pretty lightweight objects that receive notification of something, pass it on to somewhere else. and then go away. Anyway, I obviously don't know your code, so maybe this doesn't make sense.

EDIT

Sorry, I understand your problem better now. I'm used to only working with setResultData when one activity has launched another activity, and the 2nd one wants to send something back to the 1st one. But you are using it to stop an ordered broadcast, right?

Unfortunately, Android does now allow you to do what you are trying to do. This section of the doc specifically says that you cannot show a dialog from within a broadcast:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle

I think what you need to do is always return setResultData(null) right after starting your activity. If the user then clicks "no" in your dialog, then you are done. But if the user clicks "yes" (I'm assuming there is a "yes") then you would have to go ahead and make the call, and make sure you don't catch it again in your receiver.

Does that make sense? Sorry for my confusion earlier.

Comment: I added my code. as you can see i tried to share the activity result via shared preferences, how come the code is async and the setResultData(null); is called before the dialog is shown?